# How to group by one matching element in a subdocument - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have the following collection.

```
[
  {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "@pid": "131",
          "text": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "61",
          "text": "Mango"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "92",
          "text": "cherry"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "27",
          "text": "grape"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "34",
          "text": "dragonfruit"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "@pid": "131",
          "text": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "27",
          "text": "grape"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "34",
          "text": "dragonfruit"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "@pid": "131",
          "text": "Apple"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "A"
  }
]
```

I want to get the type in which apple or mango is sold, group by item name. For the above collection, the output would be :

```
{
    "_id": "Apple",
    "items" : [
        "A",
        "B",
        "A"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "Mango",
    "items" : [
        "A"
    ]
}
```

I tried the following query but it return nothing :

```
db.collection.aggregate([

     {
         $match : {
             'items.item.text' : {$regex : 'Apple|Mango'}
         }

     },
     {
        $project : {
            type : "$type"
        }
     },
     {
         $group : {
             _id : '$items.item',
                types : {$push : '$type'}

         }
     }


 ])
```

I think that even if this works, it's going to group by the entire 'items.item'. Where am I going wrong?

P.S. : I don't have the liberty to change the format of the document

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right direction. You need to use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) operator and you don't need `$project` stage in your aggregation. The below query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$items.item"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "items.item.text": {
        $regex: "Apple|Mango"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$items.item.text",
      type: {
        $push: "$type"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CP55hPVaUbZ)

Comment: Oh that worked perfectly! I was starting to think it isn't possible. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Happy to help :)